# Consequence of the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, riemann-hypothesis

So I watched this video: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rGo2hsoJSbo

And it included the fact that a consequence of RH is that there will always be a prime number between consecutive cubic numbers. I havent heard of this consequence before so First off I was wondering if this result is true if and only if the Riemann hypothesis is true and secondly I was wondering where I could see the derivation of this result.

Comment: This is also mentioned in the Wikipedia article on the [upper bounds of prime gaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds): *An immediate consequence of [Ingham's result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Ingham) is that there is always a prime number between $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3$, if n is sufficiently large.* There's also a reference to a [paper](http://zbmath.org/?q=an:1201.11111).

Comment: The analogous statement obtained by replacing *cubes* with *squares* is still widely open, even assuming RH. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture.